# Two qualified beans error when extend the interface Repository and implement the extended interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I create an interface named `UserOp` that extends `Repository`, and create a class named `UserImpl` that implements `UserOp`. When I run this program I get an error that there are two qualified beans named "`userOp`" ad "`userOpImpl`". How can I get "`userOpImpl`" only. I tried adding `@NoRepositoryBean` to interface `UserOp`, but it didn't work.

The code follows:

WebConfig.java

```
package ls2.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ls2.controllers")
@Import(Neo4jConfig.class)
// @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

Neo4jConfig.java

```
package ls2.config;

import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy.Key;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "ls2.repositories", queryLookupStrategy = Key.USE_DECLARED_QUERY)
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver")
                .setURI("file:///D:/workspace/javaweb/linkedstars/data");
        return config;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "ls2.models");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }

}
```

User.java

```
package ls2.models;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
}
```

UserController.java

```
package ls2.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import ls2.repositories.UserOp;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserOp op;

    public UserController(UserOp op) {
        this.op = op;
    }

}
```

UserOp.java

```
package ls2.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;

import ls2.models.User;

public interface UserOp extends GraphRepository<User> {

}
```

UserOpImpl.java

```
package ls2.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jOperations;

import ls2.models.User;

public class UserOpImpl extends GraphRepositoryImpl<User> implements UserOp {

    public UserOpImpl(Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations) {
        super(User.class, neo4jOperations);
    }

}
```

This project was deployed to Tomcat 9.0 and get the error that
*org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ls2.repositories.UserOp' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: userOpImpl,userOp*

Comment: can you post the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you want to [create custom implementations in your repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations).

Create a separate interface UserOpCustom

```
public interface UserOpCustom{

     /// addtitional method declarations go here

}
```

make UserOp extend that interface

```
public interface UserOp extends GraphRepository<User>, UserOpCustom {

}
```

make your implementation implement the new interface instead of the existing one.

```
public class UserOpImpl extends GraphRepositoryImpl<User> implements UserOpCustom {

    public UserOpImpl(Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations) {
        super(User.class, neo4jOperations);
    }

/// custom interface implementations go here

}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just skimmed through that document before and didn't notice it requires three units to create custom implementations. Thank you very much.  And this solution is really sophisticated and weird for me.

Comment: Yeah, remember using that the first time, took me a while to get it right, because the relationships didn't seem to make sense back than.